# Mybatis Generator Postgres return created id support

Tags: postgresql, mybatis, mybatis-generator

I'm using postgres for a project that I just started to work on, and I realized that Mybatis provide support to retrieve the autogenerated id keys for many databases but unfortunately postgres is not one of them, I modified a little bit the generated sql mappers and: 
 - changing select instead of insert in the generated xml
 - add "RETURNING id" as last line of each sentence

so it gonna look like:

```
<select id="insert" keyColumn="id" keyProperty="id" parameterType="com.myproject.Order" ...
    insert into ...
    ...
    RETURNING id
</select>
```

with that change it works like a charm but the problem is that as soon as the generator is executed again the changes should be applied again manually, I was looking for a plugin to help me to automate the changes but I did not found any that seems to help, did you do any time before something similar? what would be the recommendation?

Comment: MyBatis supports PostgreSQL's `serial` type column and with MyBatis-Generator, adding `<generatedKey column="id" sqlStatementType="JDBC">` to `<table />` element in your generator config should be sufficient ([doc](https://mybatis.org/generator/configreference/generatedKey.html)).

Comment: Could you explain how it didn't work? Generation failed or execution error? Any stack trace or error message?

Comment: Thank you for your responses, it was actually my bad, it's basically in this case for  sqlStatement=JDBC the generated value it's being returned in the same id property of the entity and not in the returned value of the function that will always return the number of rows affected (not the generated id) so I will just adjust the logic to this but will be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the explanation, I created a table `users` in a schema `mbtest`.

```sql
create table mbtest.users (
  id serial primary key,
  name varchar(20)
);
```

The below is the `<table />` element in the generator config.
(in the comment, I wrote `sqlStatementType`, but it should be `sqlStatement`)

```xml
<table tableName="users" domainObjectName="User"
    schema="mbtest">
  <generatedKey column="id" sqlStatement="JDBC" />
</table>
```

The generated 'UserMapper.xml' contains the following insert statement.
Note that `useGeneratedKeys`, `keyColumn` and `keyProperty` populated by the `<generatedKey />` above.

```xml
<insert id="insert" keyColumn="id"
    keyProperty="id" parameterType="test.model.User"
    useGeneratedKeys="true">
  <!--
    WARNING - @mbg.generated
    This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
    This element was generated on Sun Dec 08 12:36:30 JST 2019.
  -->
  insert into mbtest.users (name)
  values (#{name,jdbcType=VARCHAR})
</insert>
```

(As the WARNING says, you should  not modify the generated statements)

The `insert` statement will set the generated key to the `id` property of `User`.

```java
try (SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession()) {
  UserMapper mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(UserMapper.class);
  User user = new User();
  user.setName("User1");
  mapper.insert(user);
  sqlSession.commit();
  assertNotNull(user.getId());
}
```

Here is a [demo project](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/so-59145362/so-59145362) so that you can verify yourself.